# Jquery animate parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".div1").click(function() {
        $(".div2").stop().animate(...);
    });
});
```

**div1** and **div2** are both divs in `<div id="content">`.

I want to click div1, then div2's position will go to: `top:0px;` `left:200px;` which is relative to `<div id="content" style="width:800px;margin:0 auto;">`

How to write the animate part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass an object to [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with `top` and `left` properties, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".div1").click(function() {
        $(".div2").stop().animate({ top: 0, left: 200 });
    });
});
```

Make sure the element has a `relative` or `absolute` position set here, whichever you're going for, otherwise `top` and `left` will have no effect.

Comment: I have set content, div1, div2 all a position:relative, but have no effect.

Comment: @yuli - do they have classes or IDs? You had class selectors, so I assumed here, if they're IDs you need different selectors, e.g. `#div1` instead of `.div1`.

Comment: @yuli - here's a demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/u4kXA/ are you setup like this, something different...any JavaScript errors in your console?

Comment: OK, thanks, I will read this one, if more question, ask you again. Thanks.